# how to understand Android System destroy activity

Tags: android

From the [document](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) , i see the description below:

"The system never kills an activity directly to free up memory. Instead, it kills the process in which the activity runs, destroying not only the activity but everything else running in the process, as well. "

" if the system destroys the activity due to system constraints (such as a configuration change or memory pressure)"

It's not conflict, right? 
It means: With memory pressure, the system may kill the process. In the meantime, the system will destroy the activity ahead. So, it's not conflict.

Have I understood correctly?

If correct, does it mean that i don't need to save activity instanceState?
Because the system will relaunch the app later. It will not block the operation flow, just may need to re-input some information. Another way, i don't need to worry the old data problem, especially, the mid-status problem.